# Getting all of the pinged user in message, then check if they all have a role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

First time asking here. Sorry if I did weird stuff.
I want to get ALL of the guys that are pinged in a message, and get the roles of them, and if one of them(or some) have the staff role.

Thank you so much!

Edit:
This is my code:

```js
    message.mentions.users.forEach((user => {
        console.log(user)
        if(user.roles.cache.has('817753474791768074')) {
            message.channel.send('Stop pinging a Staff!')
        }
    }))
```

However, it can't read the property of cache. What did I do wrong?

Edit: 2

I fixed it, Guild Member and Users are different, I had to do like this

```js
    message.mentions.members.forEach((user => {
        console.log(user)
        if(user.roles.cache.has('817753474791768074')) {
            message.channel.send('Stop pinging a Staff!')
        }
    }))
```

Thank you for helping everyone, now I know how to question in stackoverflow not being so dumb.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free code writing service.
Please try to make the code by yourself and come here with errors you may encounter as your last option.

Comment: You're most likely used to using `first()` to get the first mention. Not calling `first()` will return the entire collection of mentions

Comment: Sorry. I know that `message.mentions.members` returns a collection, but I don't know how to check the roles from there.

Comment: @Elitezen but won't first() returns the first guy who gets pinged?

Comment: @Altqir `first()` returns the first element inside of a collection. Not including it will return the entire collection, from where you can use `.each()` to check every element it has or log it.

Comment: Add some code to make this question better. Show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```js
message.mentions.users.map(m => {
let role = m.roles.find(r => r.name === "Role name");
if (role) {
    //do something
}
});
```